# Is this de-structuring event target attribute or some JSX syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, es6-modules, destructuring

I got here an event handler function that's used for handling input fields' `onChange` events.

I am confused as to how `[e.target.name]` works/what exactly is doing. 
 *(I know it's getting the `name` attribute value of the targeted input field).*

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

Can someone please explains what that's doing and how it works? Much appreciated.

Comment: it's called `property accessors`, take a look at this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: if your using react 16 it's better to store the event in variable because react will update state asynchronously so the event might be gone when react want to access it. this not the case for the upcoming react 17.

Comment: @adel Updating state is done asynchronously, but the passed state argument is computed synchronously unless you are using the callback variant and pass a function to compute the new state.

Comment: @3limin4t0r   yes you are right, my bad using callback with setstate  will crash the app .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[e.target.name]` is what in JS is called a [computed property](https://ui.dev/computed-property-names/).

In simple terms, `[e.target.name]` will become an object property (key) with the value of `e.target.name`. For example, if `e.target.name` corresponds to (has a value of) `credit`, the object structure will look like this:

```js
  setFormData({
    ..formData,
    credit: e.target.value

  });
```

This is just plain JavaScript, and more specifically an [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) feature of the language.

---

Another important thing to keep in mind about React's `onChange` event handler is that it behaves quite differently from the native JS `onchange` event. Read [this post](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-onchange-differs-between-react-and-vanilla-javascript-90b56d6a340a) for more.

---

**References**

[Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)